# C# LINQ Query syntax oddity

Tags: c#, linq

Here's the simple scenario:

```
   var q = from i in icdPatientList
                        group i by i.PatientId into grp
                        select new
                        {
                            Key = grp.Key,
                            //trailing comma causes no compile-time error
                            Count = grp.Count(),
                        };
                foreach (var item in q)
                {
                    //simple columns + counts
                    Console.WriteLine(item.Key + " " + item.Count);

                }
```

Why is it that in the projection having a trailing comma with nothing after it does not cause a compile-time error?  Having two commas does, and of course having none works perfect as well.

Comment: @Moo-Juice that certainly looks like that case.  I didn't know if it was a LINQ-specific deal or not.

Comment: It's not LINQ query syntax, it's just query syntax.  The query syntax is entirely separate from LINQ.  Next, this behavior has nothing to do with query syntax, it is a question about creating anonymous types (which is also separate from LINQ).  Finally, the proposed duplicate isn't a duplicate, because anonymous types and enumeration definitions, while they both have this behavior, are two different things.

Comment: @Servy: very true on all counts. Voting to reopen. Though I suspect the answer may be very similar in terms of "this is how the spec defines it to work", just with a reference to a different part of the spec.

Comment: It seems like the consensus is "allow a trailing comma because when I comment out a line and there's a trailing comma I don't want the compiler to complain", which is a perfectly reasonable and succint answer.